# Show that a matrix $A$ is orthonormal if and only if it preserves the standard inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k$

Show that an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is orthogonal if and only if the columns of $A$ are orthonormal.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose the columns of $A$ are orthonormal. Then we have that:

$\langle Ax,Ay \rangle$

$=\sum_{k=1}^n (x_1a_{k,1}+...+x_na_{k,n})(y_1a_{k,1}+...+y_na_{k,n})$

$=\sum_{k=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{r=1}^n x_ja_{k,j}y_ra_{k,r}))$

$=\sum_{k=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{r=1}^n x_jy_ra_{k,j}a_{k,r}))$

$=\sum_{r=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{k=1}^n x_jy_ra_{k,j}a_{k,r}))$ (since finite sums commute)

$=\sum_{r=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n x_jy_r(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,j}a_{k,r}))$

$=\sum_{r=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_r(\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{j,r}))$ (since the columns of $A$ are orthonormal)

$=\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k$

I am now working on the forward direction but haven't yet finished it.

$(\rightarrow)$

Suppose now that $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle Ax,Ay \rangle$, then we have that:

$\sum_{r=1}^n x_ky_k= \langle x,y \rangle = \langle Ax,Ay \rangle = 
\sum_{k=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_r(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k,j}a_{k,r}))$

In particular,

$\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k = 
\sum_{k=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_r(\sum_{r=1}^n a_{k,j}a_{k,r}))$

If i can show that this implies that $a_{k,j}a_{k,r} = \delta_{j,r}$ then I am finished.

---

Can someone verify that my $(\leftarrow)$ direction is correct and also how to finish the $(\rightarrow)$ continuing from what I've done so far?

Also, what's the slick way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A slightly different perspective can reduce the use of summations. Note that the $j$th column of $A$ is $Ae_j$. So $(Ax, Ay) = \sum_{i, j}x_i\overline{y_j}(Ae_i, Ae_j)$. From this it follows that $A$ preserves inner products if and only if $(Ae_i, Ae_j) = (e_i, e_j)$ for all $i, j$.

Comment: Orthonormal **iff** $Q^TQ = I$. If $x^T Q^TQ y = x^Ty$ for all $x,y$ then $Q^TQ = I$.